# sequence through SQL

Tags: sql, sequence, teradata

i need to generate the following sequence through a single SQL query.

```
party1  party2
1   0
2   1
3   3
4   5
5   8
6   11
7   14
8   17
9   21
10  25
```

we should input party1 and party 2 should be generated.

Comment: It is highly dbms-specific.

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: What does `party1` even have to do with the output, other than possibly the starting number of number of terms?

Comment: nope, i am way past homework stage. working in an organization where we have to implement it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes party1 is basicaly just the sequence starter

Comment: You should tell us which database you are using (e.g. SQL Server, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no physical tables, just volatile or any inner query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there any dbc table from whihc i can get the number 1?

Comment: You **need** to tell us which database you are using.  This isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there any dbc table that stores integars?

Comment: it is unclear how the party2 is calculated

Comment: @cha it is basically a sequence of powers of 2

Comment: Why is your sequence is different to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#The_first_96_powers_of_two)?

Comment: Your sequence is like : [Sorting numbers](https://oeis.org/A001855) ;).

Comment: @shA.t but how to write this in sql

Comment: If you already got the `party1` row you can use this calculation in Teradata (based on @a_horse_with_no_name's formula): `Cast(party1*Ceil(Ln(party1)/Ln(2)) - 2**Ceil(Ln(party1)/Ln(2)) + 1 AS BIGINT)`

Answer (score 0):

According [to the link](https://oeis.org/A001855) that shA.t posted, the formula is:

```
n*ceiling(log_2 n) - 2^ceiling(log_2(n)) + 1
```

In Postgres this can be written as:

```
select n as party1
       (n*ceiling(log(2.0, n)) - 2^ceiling(log(2.0, n)) + 1)::int as party2
from generate_series(1,10) x(n);
```

As the question is only tagged with `sql` the following is ANSI SQL (except for the `log()` function):

```
with recursive numbers (n) as (
  values (1)
  union
  select p.n + 1
  from numbers p
  where p.n <= 9
)
select n, cast(n*ceiling(log(2.0, n)) - power(2,ceiling(log(2.0, n))) + 1 as integer)
from numbers;
```

For databases not supporting (recursive) common table expression, simply create the numbers table:

```
create table numbers (n integer);
insert into numbers (n)
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

Comment: do i have to make the table numbers?

Comment: @user3296651: it's a common table expression that generates the numbers. You don't need to create the table

Comment: i am getting error. expected smth like a select keyword  or a '(' or a transactionTime keyword or a nontemporal keyword between '(' and values keyword

Comment: @user3296651: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: i am using using teradata sql assistant

Comment: @user3296651: then maybe Teradata doesn't support common table expressions. Or the `values()` row constructor. I don't know. You can simply create a numbers table if you want to

Comment: `with recursive numbers (n) as (select 1 from (select 1)t(c) union all ...`